# Can ibuprofen and paracetamol be taken together?

Tags: headache, drug-interactions, nsaids-pain-meds, analgesics, acetaminophen

I have a headache I've been meaning to get rid of this morning. I do know the differences between paracetamol and ibuprofen however since I just woke up this morning with my thoughts still cloudy, I've impulsively decided to take a dose of paracetamol (500mg) to alleviate my head ache. It was only later that I realized that it was muscle pains near my shoulder that was causing my headache and that I should've taken ibuprofen instead.

Is it safe to take ibuprofen (200mg) if I've already taken paracetamol 5 hours before?

Comment: Personal medical advice is off-topic here (see https://health.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) so I have taken out some of the details to make the question more general. If you disagree with my changes, feel free to edit the question again. Welcome to Health.SE!

Comment: Related: https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/4052/are-there-any-untoward-synergistic-effects-in-taking-a-combination-of-acetaminop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is safe. The mechanism that ibuprofen and paracetamol use are different and don't interact negatively. In fact, the two drugs (medicines) can be used in conjunction for a synergistic effect so that it will provide greater pain relief than either drug alone. With that said, still follow the standard dosing instructions for each drug. That means don't take more than 3000 Mg of paracetamol in one day (24 hours) (this is a strict limit, can cause permanent damage  if you exceed 4000 mg in 24 hours) and don't take more than 1200 mg of ibuprofen in any 24 hour period or you risk stomach bleeding. Hope this helps :) 
Sources: http://www.nhs.uk/chq/Pages/857.aspx?CategoryID=73
[Acetaminophen with ibuprofen](http://m.goodrx.com/blog/is-it-safe-to-take-tylenol-acetaminophen-with-advil-or-motrin-ibuprofen)

Comment: Sources? Those would be particularly important when you're dispensing medical advice.

Comment: http://www.nhs.uk/chq/Pages/857.aspx?CategoryID=73

Comment: See the "edit" link beneath your answer? Please click that and add the link to your answer.

Comment: You should know that [not every researcher thinks the combination is perfectly safe](http://ard.bmj.com/content/70/9/1521.full).